# Refresh Parent Component While navigating From Child Component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am loading some backend api data on homepage in `ngOnInit()`

```
export class MyComponent{
 homepagedata:any; // displayed on the html 

ngOnInit() {
   this.homepagedata=// calling service 
}

}
```

This is my routes

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [


        {  
            path: 'dashboard/:userid', // 
            component: DashboardComponent,
        },

    ]
}
```

So when I navigate to dashboard ,and then navigate again to home ,my home component doesn't gets refreshed ,may be because `ngOnInit()` is called once .How to call this `ngOnit()` every time I navigate to home.I tried with `ngAfterViewInit()` but its also only called once.

I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197732/update-parent-component-when-navigating-from-child-component-angular).But here it is navigating after the function call ,which is not in my case .There are many child components in my case ,and I am looking for one solution that can fit all.Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you can have your parent component listen for route changes and update your data accordingly:

```
export class MyComponent {
    homepageData: any;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
       this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
         if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {    
             // update this.homepageData
       });
     }
     ...
}
```

Comment: That's a purely genius .I think I should be rewarded for asking such question :P .Its not available anywhere.Thanks :)

Comment: Make sure to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy to prevent memory leaks. Also, this should be put into ngOnInit.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to listen to the router event corresponding to the navigation to your home page and load data when it happens.
Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-route-update) demonstrating a possible implementation.

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <p>home page content (load count: {{loadCount}})</p>
        <hr>
        <p>child page:</p>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
})
export class HomeComponent
{
    loadCount = 0;

    constructor ( private router: Router )
    {
        // On router event...
        this.router.events
            // ...if event is a navigation end and if target is home page...
            .pipe(filter(event =>
                event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.urlAfterRedirects === '/home',
            ))
            // ...load data.
            .subscribe(() => this.load());
    }

    private load ()
    {
        // Simulate data loading by incrementing a counter.
        console.log('load home data');
        this.loadCount++;
    }
}
```